# CSS margin-bottom collapsed - but why?

Tags: css, margin

I have this simple xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="height: 100%;">
<head>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%;">
  <div style="height: 100%; overflow: auto; background-color: #00f;">
    <div style="height: 400px; margin-bottom: 2000px; background-color: #f00;"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It shows two rectangles - but the lower (blue) one doesn't show the 2000px margin. It is only as tall as the window. Why? Or more importantly, how do I make it to show? I can add some dummy text like 'aaa' between those two `</div>` `</div>` but I don't feel that's the right way of doing it.

Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want 2000px of blue beneath the 400px div, make this change:

*Change the height of the containing div to be the height of it's contents + the 2000px space.*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="height: 100%;">

<head> </head>

<body style="height: 100%;">

  <div style="height: 2400px; overflow: auto; background-color: #00f;">

    <div style="height: 400px; background-color: #f00;">
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `height: 100%` from `<body>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="height: 100%;">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="height: 100%; overflow: auto; background-color: #00f;">
    <div style="height: 400px; margin-bottom: 2000px; background-color: #f00;"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `height` declaration in the blue background div.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="height: 100%;">
<head>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%;">
  <div style="background-color: #00f;overflow:auto">
    <div style="height: 400px; margin-bottom: 2000px; background-color: #f00;"></div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have a height set on the containing div. Margins aren't content, so they don't trigger overflow. You could add another div around the innermost div, and give it a 1px padding, or, as others have suggested, you could adjust your existing containing divs.

Answer (score 0):

lotusvskoi: Thanks but then the body scrolls, not the outer div.

endash: Yes! This is it! Thank you a lot, also for the explanation. Wrapping the innermost div inside another div with padding: 1px works great!

Final version, for archiving:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="height: 100%;">
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%;">
<div style="height: 100%; overflow: auto; background-color: #00f;">
<div style="padding-bottom: 1px;">
<div style="height: 400px; margin-bottom: 2000px; background-color: #f00;">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```